# Is there a npm library that converts html to pdf that support Angular and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, pdf, html, css, angular

Is there a npm library that converts html to pdf that support Angular and Bootstrap?

I have a requirement that converts the html file into pdf.

I tried pdfmake npm library but it doesn't support bootstrap and only few css tags can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an npm library called "[jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)" that can be used to convert HTML to PDF and supports Angular and Bootstrap. It allows you to add custom CSS and also provides various options to customize the PDF output such as adding headers, footers, page numbers, etc.

[Live Demo](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html)

Here is the [Documentation](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html) for more information.